# The best way to implement the function for open/close label

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress listing page where 200 shops are listed, so I have PHP function which shows open/close label depending on working time:

```
$status = open_close_status($restaurant_id);
<span class="restaurant-status <?php echo $status; ?>"><?php echo $status; ?></span>
```

The problem is that labels are cached and stay the same even if page is reloaded. What is the best way to implement such a function so that PHP stays dynamic? need to exclude from being cached only this piece of code but rest of page should be cached.

Comment: Cached where? Do you have some sort of WordPress cache installed?

Comment: Yes , its wp-fastest-cache

Comment: Does it work when you turn it off?

Comment: there is option to exclude page from caching, when i enable that it  works but load is slow since it prevents the whole page from being cached

Comment: Figure out why it is slow. Perhaps it is the query.

Comment: its slow because of cloud server, TTFB is very slow , so with plugin i can boost loading speed, but dynamic php become static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages with dynamic content shouldn't be server cached, or should have their cache updated by the server (cron job perhaps) every five minutes or so. It sounds like you have a query problem. Perhaps lazily load any restaurants past a certain point, and make sure you're not using a meta query.

To fix your problem as it stands, however, you'll need to dynamically update the statuses with JavaScript, specifically AJAX. Take a look at [WP's AJAX Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for a quick overview on how it works.

Essentially you'll need to replace your status HTML/PHP with just `<span class="restaurant-status" data-restaurant-id="<?php echo $restaurant_id;"></span>`. Then from there you can grab and loop through all of the restaurant statuses with JavaScript, and pass the ID's to your `open_close_status` function (make sure to add them to the [`wp_ajax_nopriv_`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) action hook, modify the class, and change the inner text.

That said, I still believe you should address your pages slowness first, outside of server caching. Lazy loading, making sure images are compressed, not relying heavily on slow/bloated plugins, etc. WordPress should be able to spit out 10, 50, 100, or even 200 posts very quickly. (As anecdotal evidence, I've got a site I'm working on with 400,000 records in the posts table, 35,000 are "companies", and 350,000 are "reviews", all associated to each other, and it can spit out 250 companies and their reviews in less than half a second.)

Comment: Xhynk thank you for detailed reply. I am retrieving data from mysql using get_post_meta() function.I implemented lazy load, compressed images as well but still have TTFB  3.9 seconds. I thought about AJAX, but imagine 200 or 400 requests per one user , or maybe its ok ?

Comment: "350,000 are "reviews", all associated to each other, and it can spit out 250 companies and their reviews in less than half a second." May be  you had been using dedicated plan but mine is cloud

Comment: If you're using posts based on meta data, don't do that. Meta Values are, by default, *not indexed* in the database, causing them to be incredibly slow. Try changing your query to just fetching 200 restaurants without rely on meta data. I bet you can get your TTFB to under 1.5 seconds if not even better. You can try adding a small index on your `meta_value` column, but you're probably better using something else that's already indexed like taxonomy terms instead of post meta.

Comment: @ Xhynk, sorry for late replay , thank you so much for your helping, i will try to change the format of query , and let you know if it works.